# How can I sync two equivalent tables in different DBs using Hibernate ?

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I am trying to design a code in *Java* which will sync **table A** on a database with **table A** on another database. Can this efficiently be done using Hibernate?

Comment: This sounds like a job that could be done more effectively using oracle sql and pl/sql alone. Is there a specific reason why you are designing in java?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe database replication is the best way to do, but if you MUST do that for any reason, then you should look at some sheduler like [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

Quartz is well integrated with the Spring Framework, so it could be a good way to program a **Job** which do the replication as many times per day as necessary. Be carefull about datas flow, and synchronization process with transactions, it could do some datas integrity problems (which could "provide" some unwanted deadlocks...).

Anyway you could have as many hibernate.cfg.xml as you have databases connections.
So you could store your objet at the same time in the two databases, but it could be an heavy solution which will probably impact application response time.